# Google Spreadsheet returns ”xml content cannot be parsed”

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I try to import data into a google spreadsheet using importxml, but every time I try I get the same error: ”The imported xml content cannot be parsed”. (The original message is german, I translated.)

The data I want do import is located in the h1 of a amazon product page. As an example I use the following: https://www.amazon.de/Harry-Potter-verwunschene-Special-Rehearsal/dp/3551559007/.

Do you understand why the following does not work?

```
=importXml("https://www.amazon.de/Harry-Potter-verwunschene-Special-Rehearsal/dp/3551559007/"; "//h1/span[1]")
```

I appreciate every helping hand!

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions.  Google spreadsheet questions are more suited for [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets).

Answer (score 0):

SO it's now being loaded by javascript so if you take that last number on the end of your URL `3551559007` and append it onto this URL string `https://www.amazon.de/gp/search-inside/service-data?method=getBookData&asin=` you will see the raw JSON where the data is - and you can parse it from there:

`https://www.amazon.de/gp/search-inside/service-data?method=getBookData&asin=3551559007`

so in this case you can basically us this formula to get out the title:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(CONCATENATE(IMPORTDATA(A1)),"(^.*title:"")(.*)(""type:""html.*)","$2")
```

[image]

or you can find the import json custom function and set that all up - the above will be quicker.